# How to protect log from application crash?

Tags: c++, logging, crash, fstream

I've created a simple logger which, well, logs everything of importance into a text file. I'm using `std::ofstream` but there's a problem - when the program doesn't close the file (call `std::ofstream::close()`) for whatever reason (like crash), the created log is actually empty (0 size). And since the log is most useful in exceptional situations (when something goes wrong) - you see the problem.

Is there any way to protect my log from that? I could try closing the file after writing every couple of lines and using append - but that still doesn't protect me from the situation when the program crashes in the middle of logging/before closing the file. Is there any solution or am I just doomed?

Comment: If it is mission critical information I would just open and close the log on each write. If the log would grow over time then you could employ a rolling log type solution with a "capped" size.

Comment: @KendrickLamar But when I open (append) already created file to add something and never close it (e.g. crash) the file still gets corrupted.

Comment: An error log should never be extremely Huge. That's why I suggested opening the file prior to writes and then closing the file afterwards. Is threading an issue her?

Comment: @KendrickLamar What are you talking about? I'm saying that if I open the file (call `std::ofstream::open()`) and fail to close it (for whatever reason) then the result (physical) file has the size of 0 (and I lose all the log information).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Then your logging needs exception handling. File writes should be pretty plain/jane and never jack up your application code. If you are worried about crashing during a log write then I would suggest using shadow files. What os are you using?

Comment: @KendrickLamar Windows (7 64-bit) What are shadow files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should employ **[flush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush)** method, it is there to precisely solve problems like the one you're facing.

There is another approach which can be considered more safe, but requires substantially more effort to implement and test. The approach boils down to what is known as **[inter-process communication (IPC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)**. In brief, you could implement your logger as a separate *logger application* which would *communicate* with your target application by means of specific *protocol* (interface). You can develop such protocol by yourself or employ one of the existing ones (which are usually very generic, i.e. general purpose). As a result, if your target application crashes, it doesn't drag logger application with it, and therefore logger can safely finish its job.

That approach is usually used by some huge, complex, and safety-critical systems. However, I guess that in your case this is definitely an overkill and bare `flush()` after each append is more than enough.

Comment: Always knew it but never thought it actually does **this**. :P But what happens if I `flush()` but don't `close()`?

Comment: Nothing, the contents which are _flushed_ are already there in the file (physically). In other words, if you forget (or can't) to `close()`, only the information **after** the last `flush()` can be lost.

Comment: IPC not only is an overkill but it actually doesn't solve the problem at all - as the logging process might crash just as well (and the same unsaved data problem occurs).

Comment: No, it cannot crash as long as it's well-tested lightweight application which provides bare logging facilities, and no exotic/hardcore business logic, algorithms, etc. (the ones which are usually the subject to crash). By the way, it didn't imply that logger application doesn't use `flush()` facility itself, of course it does.

Comment: You can only keep the risk to minimum - theoretically even the simplest application can always have bugs and in extreme situations even crash. Or let's say I have some other evil process in the system that kills my logging process just for fun. :P

Comment: Yes, sure if we go to such extreme cases, then my mom could also come to PC and cut the power cable with scissors, yelling at me to go to bed. Not only the logger would crash, but if I'm incredibly lucky I could end-up reinstalling OS and/or buying new hardware. So it's good that I live alone now. `;)`

Comment: Yes but to be serious - the more I can get my code fireproof the better, I think.

Comment: I've also posted a related question (for anyone interested): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268433/what-does-stdofstreamclose-actually-do

Answer (score 2):

In our commercial application, we had a very robust solution for that. The price was non-portability.

We installed a Vectored Exception Handler. This handler is called in case of an unhandled OS exception, before the program exits (which is by far the most common crash). When it's called, you can not call C++ Standard Library function anymore (or even C functions). Even `fflush` is unreliable.

Yet it is OK to call basic OS functions. Be careful, though. Setting up the arguments for the OS call shouldn't use `malloc` either. Have the name of the crashfile already set up before the crash actually happens, etc. Do close the file immediately, again using OS functions.

Comment: >Do close the file immediately, again using OS functions. *Reply*: How to achieve this goal by non-OS functions?

Comment: >installed a Vectored Exception Handler. *Reply*: Could you please show me a simple demo snippet to fully understand how it works?

Comment: @John: MSDN has [an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/using-a-vectored-exception-handler). And I'll repeat my warning: non-OS functions must not be called after the exception happens. `CreateFile` and `WriteFile` are generally OK. No need for `flush`, call `CloseFile`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please explain in more detail about why **non-OS** functions **must not** be called after the exception happens?

Comment: @John: It's unspecified how those functions rely on their runtime, and in general your process state is wildly unknown. The runtime can be entirely broken - it's not uncommon for the Vectored Exception to happen in response to heap corruption, or buffer overflows, or a host of other state-corrupting errors.

Comment: So, **OS** functions do not have the said problems?

Comment: @John: Much less so. However, do use common sense. Call `CreateFileW`, not `CreateFileA` (if you weren't already using Unicode). But that's part of what I said earlier - make sure that you have the filename ready before the crash happens.

Comment: I see, thank you. Do you think `flush()` should be called every time when writing every single message to prevent data loss which is caused by the program suddenly crashes.