# What does std::ofstream::close() actually do?

Tags: c++, fstream, flush

This question: [How to protect log from application crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267984/how-to-protect-log-from-application-crash) has lead me to another - what does `std::ofstream::close()` actually do? I know it calls `flush()` and that's one thing. But what else? What closing the file actually is?

Edit:
Let me rephrase my question - **is anything physically done to the actual file** during the call to `close()` or is it just `std::ofstream` internal cleanup stuff?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Other than flushing the userspace buffers, i.e. `flush()`, `close(2)` is called on the underlying file-descriptor. It depends on the operating system what happens then, but most likely nothing happens to the actual storage occupied by the file.

What *will* happen is that the (if the file descriptor was the last reference in that process to that file) file entry associated with the file gets removed from the open-file table of the process. I.e. freeing process-associated kernel-memory.

Comment: >Other than flushing the userspace buffers, i.e. `flush()`, `close(2)` is called on the underlying file-descriptor. *Reply*: Which `flush()`? You mean `std::ofstream::flush()` or `fflush(3)` or ?

Answer (score 11):

Here is the trace of calls from documentation:

---

```
void std::basic_ofstream::close();
```

Effectively calls `rdbuf()->close()`. If an error occurs during operation, `setstate(failbit)` is called.

---

```
std::basic_streambuf<CharT,Traits>* std::basic_ofstream::rdbuf() const;
```

Returns the associated stream buffer. If there is no associated stream buffer, returns `NULL`.

---

`std::basic_streambuf` actually inherits `std::basic_filebuf`, therefore:

---

```
std::basic_filebuf<CharT, Traits>* std::basic_filebuf::close();
```

If a put area exist (e.g. file was opened for writing), first calls `overflow(Traits::eof())` to write all pending output to the file, including any unshift sequences.

If the most recently called function, out of `underflow()`, `overflow()`, `seekpos()`, and `seekoff()`, was `overflow()`, then calls `std::codecvt::unshift()`, perhaps multiple times, to determine the unshift sequence according to the imbued locale, and writes that sequence to file with `overflow(Traits::eof())`.

Then, closes the file as if by calling `std::fclose`, regardless of whether any of the preceding calls succeeded or failed.

**NOTE:** `close()` is typically called through the destructor of `std::basic_filebuf` (which, in turn, is typically called by the destructor of `std::basic_fstream`.

---

First of all, we can see that it doesn't actually call `flush()` directly as you expected. Nevertheless, the *flushing* effect indeed occurs in the `std::basic_filebuf::close()` method. In addition, we can see that it still does a bit of tampering with a file, i.e. writing the unshift sequence. Nothing else special happens then, the file simply closes.

Pay attention to the **NOTE** above: in most cases you don't even need to call `std::basic_ofstream::close()` explicitly.

Comment: "unshift sequences"? What's that?

Answer (score 2):

Closes the file currently associated with the object, disassociating it from the stream.

Any pending output sequence is written to the file.

If the stream is currently not associated with any file (i.e., no file has successfully been open with it), calling this function fails.

The file association of a stream is kept by its internal stream buffer:
Internally, the function calls rdbuf()->close(), and sets failbit in case of failure.

Note that any open file is automatically closed when the ofstream object is destroyed.

From: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/close/

Comment: I've rephrased my question, please see the edit of the original post.

Comment: >Note that any open file is automatically closed when the ofstream object is destroyed. *Reply*: will the `ofstream` object be *auto* destroyed when the program crashes? I think the answer is no.